# Learning Graphic Design

Tags: tutorial, education

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips and sources for programmers who must or want to learn graphic design.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-sources-for-programmers-who-must-or-want-to-learn-graphic-design)

I would like to learn the basics of graphic design. I am a programmer, but I often end up giving my opinion on design aesthetics to others in my (small) company. I'd like to be able to give more concise and helpful feedback, and enhance the appearance of my own projects.

I'm looking for books that can teach me the basics of graphic design and give me some room to grow. Please keep answers specifically to books.

Comment: It's not a book, so I'm making it a comment, but I wrote an article on this very subject a few weeks ago: http://www.virtuosimedia.com/design/theory/design-basics-for-programmers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tips and sources for programmers who must or want to learn graphic design.](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-sources-for-programmers-who-must-or-want-to-learn-graphic-design). In here you will find your questions answered :)

Comment: Actually, I was looking specifically for books - I saw the other question, but there were not many books given in its answers. Additionally, there was precious little commentary on the books that were given. The two questions have some overlap, but this question covers a very specific area in which the other question lacks.