# How to combine pictures to relate them to the person who viewed these pictures?

Tags: composition, conceptualization, communication

I have a lot of video footage in first person view, dramatic scenery, and a photo of an old man.

I want to combine them to make a background picture (1920 x 1080) that should transmit the message: this is what he saw, this is what shaped his face.

I came up with a picture mosaic, mixing pictures of the raw footage, but I found this unconvincing.

[image: mosaic of pictures from video footage]

Then I thought about showing the face of the old man and putting footage into his eyes as a reflection, but that would limit me to one or two pictures of the footage.

How can I combine more pictures while conveying the idea of the first person point of view?

Comment: Hi, we don't do general open-ended brainstorming here (see http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq), and also this seems really really really specific to one task. Can you try to figure out what the underlying problem is you're trying to solve, and edit this into a question that can be answered on that underlying problem? There might be something answerable under here - for example, to do with how to suggest a story in an images without it becoming too busy...?

Comment: If not, you could try asking for ideas at an art forum (like http://www.deviantart.com maybe?). That said, this sounds a bit like a college creative thinking exercise - if it is, you won't get much out of it by having someone else do the thinking! You could try researching about creative thinking techniques: there's a few pointers in this [older question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/how-do-i-learn-to-be-creative) ), and feel free to ask if you have any specific design-related creative thinking questions.

Comment: I feel offended by the expectation that someone else gave me this task. I myself came up with it and I want you or someone else to contribute your ideas. I am specifically interested in other points of view regarding this very issue. You sound like a computer that needs binary input and who is overwhelmed by everything else.

Comment: But I created a thread in deviantart for those being not that narrow-minded: http://forum.deviantart.com/art/digital/1789901/

Comment: @RichartBremer: Sorry if you are offended. Stack Exchange is meant for concrete, answerable questions which are going to help others as well. You are asking for others to give you ideas about specific aspects of a single project, which is not very applicable to others. SE is rather "narrow-minded" that way.

Comment: There's an important line between asking for help solving a general type problem, and asking other people to do work specific to your project for you. We're happy to help, we're just trying to suggest ways that you can bring this question onto the right side of that line. (p.s. what would be wrong with someone else having giving you the task? Being given tasks by other people is how most of us earn a living! :-) Self-initiated work is fine too, of course, but there's absolutely nothing wrong with working to briefs set by clients...)

Comment: Wow. One piece of general advice: when asking people you don't know to give you free help, being rude or hostile to them does not improve the chances of people choosing to help you. Especially when they are using their experience of a community to try to help you pitch your question in a way that people are more likely to be interested in answering.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [principle of proximity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_grouping#Proximity) to highlight the different relationships between pictures.

For example, you may group pictures from the video footage with limited white space between images on one side, to indicate a close relationship, and add the picture of the old man on the other side, with larger white space between the old man and the group, to indicate a different, looser relationship.

Comment: +1 (also, nice edit! Much more like a real design question :-) )