# How to approach the creation of a personal logo

Tags: logo, workflow

I need advice on creating a personal logo. **I am stuck.**

I have done one professional logo for a friend before, It was for a *trust*, the logo came out well because I know what the logo represented very clearly... not that I don't know about myself, but I can't seem to think of anything to represent me the way I could for that *trust*

**I am not asking you to suggest a logo for me (since I will be figuring that out myself), what I need to know is how you guys go about it, a *personal* logo?**

> Things it should(n't) represent
>
> - Logo ≠ My name (Any alphabets/word, I am not good at typography)
> - Logo ≈ Image (Something I may hand draw and trace-out)
> - Logo  ≠ Brand ( I am not a graphic designer by profession, hence I don't need it for business)
> - Logo ≠ Hobby ( Camera as my logo? Nope! )

**So what other things a logo can represent about a person?**

Answer (score 2):

Also understand your are basically trying to figure out the one area that every designer will battle.  Even now if you find a logo that you like in a couple of months or a year you are going to want something better.

to extend on plainclothes design something in the area you enjoy.  Example: if you like illustration draw yourself.  You not only can perfect your skills but you are practicing on yourself.

The key to this is experimentation and your best solution, as stated, will be scribbling until something clicks and you are open with ideas.  If you are going to do something with the initials "RPS" Google it as RPS logos and see what others have done.  Spend about an hour a day at logo inspiration sites.  I sometimes get my best work from an idea or a spin-off of something someone created.

Comment: I have to disagree about crawling others' work. I prefer to spend little to no time in this activity. An hour a day seems grossly excessive to me. I would spend time seeking inspiration in areas of culture that stir your passion: science, art, music, literature.

Comment: how are you crawling others' work and then post going to artistic places for inspiration an issue?  Not many people are fortunate to have artistic places and aren't your ideas of inspiration basically coming from the same thing with the only difference of being in a physical location and not online?

Comment: Physical location not required. I'll amend my answer with more on that topic. Design is a reflection of culture. I think it's best to look to the source for inspiration rather than the work of others who are reflecting that source. Looking at other people's conclusion may inspire you, but it's much more likely to sway you toward mimicry.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but it would appear that just by looking at it online would influence someone to plagiarize when you can still plagiarize visiting the direct art form. I think it would then fall morally on someone's discretion not to blatantly copy another persons work regardless of the venue or the level of art form being displayed.

Comment: When developing a symbol or logotype, looking at other designers' symbols and logotypes is quite different from looking at fine art, listening to music, or reading. Perhaps I'm just a stuffy academic ;)

Answer (score 2):

How about an old school answer - you're creating a "bug" as apposed to a logo. A bug is the Nike Swoosh, the McDonald's Arches and things like that. Without words, it's a bug.

Now, the bug gives you a lot of range to express yourself. As you walk around your world, keep some paper handy. Write down words or doodle things that represent you. The way a leaf looks. The texture of leather. The rims on a classic car. The word "Enjoy" or something that moves you. It could be anything so be open to inspiration.

In the past week, I did 12 logo variations for two projects and they all began with a bug element. Then various fonts and words. Finally, colors and textures. Try a few ideas - that's what erasers are for. In short, there is no right or wrong way to get there, just a journey of discovery.

Comment: A bug is something temporary, promotional, junk. You're making a symbol to last. Something that can combine well with a logotype and be used as a full-fledged personal mark. Don't call it a *bug*!

Answer (score 1):

**Spend a few minutes each morning scribbling:** Words, ideas, icons, images that depict pieces of who you are and what you do, anything and everything that comes into your head. Then try to categorize those things and see what patterns emerge.

**Ask the people who know you** why they hang around you, why you stand out in their minds. Find the high points that are uniquely you, then symbolize that amalgam.

Or, just make a monogram.

---

**When looking for general inspiration**, I look out away from design and the commercial world.

- **Music**: I make an iTunes playlist full of powerful sounds that play with the mind a little (John Cage, Cabaret Voltaire, Sculthorpe, Nancarrow, etc). Even better, go to the orchestra.
- **Science & Tech**: I read a few pages of "[Advice for a Young Investigator](http://amzn.com/0262681501)". See what's new in the news ([I like Wired](http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/)). Or look through some really old ideas about the topic on [Bibliodyssey](http://bibliodyssey.blogspot.com/).
- **Art**: I break out [a dusty old art history book](http://amzn.com/0810934019) or [two](http://amzn.com/0131830635). I could stay there all day so I have to give myself a time limit ;) Museums are good when you have 'em.
- **Literature**: I'm a sucker for reading. Read about topics that captivate you. For me it's things like "[The Art of War](http://amzn.com/1469259435)", [Poe](http://amzn.com/1475141424), or [historical documents](http://amzn.com/0486411249).
- **Nature**: Go hiking. Get on your bike. Isolate yourself with just the out-of-doors and your thoughts.

I give structure to this process by following the ideas in [A Technique for Producing Ideas](http://amzn.com/B001QB48SW). I've mentioned this here [before in greater detail](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/13192/4216).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered doing something a little more abstract?
The logo could not be anything in particular, but be designed to convey a vibe that would represent you.

Like would you consider yourself as "rounded" or "sharp"? (shape)

Are you "vibrant" or "cooler"? (color)

Although this may not end up becoming a logo, it could help you think in a right direction without being overwhelmed.

For example, my profile pic right now roughly resembles my initials (M.L), but mostly uses design elements to get a certain feel.

Comment: You may want to check post dates. `:)` You're merely bumping 8-10 year old questions. The users who posted the questions are probably long gone.

Comment: Ah, whoops. So that's how it works. I'll avoid that next time.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong `:)` Input (an answer) can be invaluable to anyone who stumbles upon the question, via a Google search, because they have a similar issue, even *years* later. But you generally shouldn't expect *any* further input from the user who posted the original question. I don't mean to dissuade you from answering anything, regardless of its age. `:)`