# How to get one's creative juices flowing again?

Tags: drawing, ink

I wanted to post this in case anyone else is going through what I am experiencing. I haven't done a lot of artwork in the past few years. I was trying to get back into a grove. But, I found that I was trying to do these big projects that I would always stop shortly after starting. (I do 3D projects in SketchUp and also do a lot of pencil and pen drawing. I sometimes use Paint.Net. I have started to work with Inkscape. Many years ago I took some college classes on Photoshop, Illustrator and some other graphic programs. Having worked as a board artist and having done a lot of pen and ink drawing in the past before there were computers, I really thought the Pen tool was the coolest thing ever. I still enjoy using it. )

OK - So...I was trying to get back to doing some creative work. I found a Zentangle book in the library just by chance. I flipped through it and saw some nice ink work. I took it home and tried it out. It got me going again. I am pretty sure that it was because you work with a small space (3.5" x 3.5") and go through a sequence of steps to get going. And, that's what it did: It got me going. I was able to actually finish some Zentangle projects. I took photos of some designs and I'm planning on reworking them in Inkscape. I am also going to try to do some bigger works. The more I do the little squares, the more I see that ideas are coming to me more easily. I don't really copy the ideas in the books. But, I do flip through them and try to modify some of the basic ideas.

Comment: This reads more like a general story than a question. You may want to review some other questions here:  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20963/how-to-get-motivated-when-drained and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/how-do-i-learn-to-be-creative

Comment: I closed your question since it looks more like an answer. Check out the one I marked, http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13178/how-do-you-break-out-of-current-creative-mind-sets/13206#13206 -- you're welcome to leave this as an Answer to that question. It still gets LOTS of views.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Ryan. I know other artists go through this "block" from time to time. Thought I could offer a bit of help or an idea.

Answer (score 1):

- doodle
- take a shower
- go for a walk
- do drugs
- go the library
- watch a movie
- try a new medium of art
- draw with your other hand
- talk to people
- people watch
- photography
- listen to music
- exercise
- meditate
- the list is infinite...