# how to design visually beautifull websites?

Tags: website-design, design-principles, visualization

I have a good knowledge of HTML, CSS, Javascript and ... 
and I can make an entire website in 2 or 3 days but I don't know how to make it beautiful an attractive!! can you tell what should I do coz I don't know how to design actually!! if anybody knows a book, website or an online course that can help I really appreciate it .. tnx a lot guys

Comment: Hi Ershad, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Please have a look at our existing questions [Tips and resources for beginnin designers](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-resources-for-beginning-designers) and [How do I learn to be creative](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/how-do-i-learn-to-be-creative) and their answers. I think you'll find a lot of useful information there!

Comment: What is "beautiful" for you? Must it the same for me? What is "attractive" for you? Must it be the same for me? I think not. Please rethink your question ...

Comment: @Ershad I can relate with you. This is my first visit to this website, and I came here seeking the same broad advice.

Answer (score 1):

Wow. That's like saying: "I have good design skills but I don't know to turn my design into a functioning website. Can you tell me how to write HTML, CSS, Javascript etc?"

There is a lot involved here and we don't really know you or your background. I suppose the key here is for you to have an idea of what topics you have to cover and for you to understand that developing your design skills is a process.

To be a good designer you have to understand  how the eye and mind is attracted and pulled by color, typography; and the balance and rhythm created by the placement and proportion of visual items. You will not become a designer over night - just as a designer cannot learn HTML and CSS overnight or the intricacies of producing something that works.

How long do you think it will take a someone with no coding experience to understand floats v display:inline-block; the use of clearfix, of pseudo-elements; of resolving conflicting CSS styles - not to mention having a clear understanding of javascript hoisting and closures?

The short answer is one cannot be an expert designer and an expert front-end developer at the same time. But everyone can expand their skill set which is what I think you're trying to do.

So what should you do? Wow. There are so many places to start.
The classes at Lynda.com are excellent. It's well worth the $25/mth. Take beginner design courses; take typography courses; learn color theory. If you're working on sites with tons of data then Tufte is a perfect bridge between the various worlds

Eventually you may also considering reading up on UX and IA.  If so look up Krug, Jakob Nielsen, Donald Norman. Those names should be enough to take you down the UX rabbit-hole.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [these](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/fundamentals-of-design) courses on Website/App design on CodeSchool, it might help you. They are complete and show you how to choose the correct fonts, colors, and layout, according to wich type of website you want to build.

You can also pay to have more, but I didn't have the occasion to try it out.

I guess I can't give you any personal advice, because your question is quite vague...And we all have our vision of beautiful websites

Comment: Hi TrakJohnson, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm just a beginner, learning the basics....