# Recommendations for design process books

Tags: website-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips and sources for beginning designers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-sources-for-beginning-designers)

I am interested in user centred design. I practice web design, but I think the design process in general is useful from all fields. Does anyone have a good recommendation for a interesting look at the design process. Possible implementation strategies.

Comment: You'll find this has been well answered here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-sources-for-beginning-designers

Comment: @Alan: That question doesn't really list any books or resources specific to teaching the design _process_. They're more general design resources/tips (websites for inspiration, web design/development blogs like A List Apart, etc.). A book teaching the design process would be something like [_Communicating Design_](http://www.amazon.com/Communicating-Design-Developing-Documentation-Planning/dp/0321712463/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) by Dan Brown (a different one).

Comment: Another good one (and which focuses on UCD) is [_Designing the Obvious_](http://www.amazon.com/Designing-Obvious-Approach-Application-Edition/dp/0321749855/) by Robert Hoekman.

Answer (score 1):

Steve Krug's [*Don't Make Me Think*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321344758) is an excellent book on designing web usability.

Comment: thanks I have this book actually, I am looking for a book more on the process of rational design or the action-centric design process. The steps involved more or less.