# Graphic Design resource for game project?

Tags: games

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips and sources for beginning designers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-sources-for-beginning-designers)

I'm creating my first game and want to improve upon the graphic design aspects of my game.

By graphic design I mean layout, font, spacing, etc..

Is there a good resource for learning graphic design for a programmer?

I've taken human-computer interaction classes, but that has more to do with task and making task as easy as possible for the user. Not necessarily about layout/spacing.

I mention layout/spacing twice because that's the biggest problem I'm having. I can clearly tell that things need to be spaced properly to be more visually pleasing.

Thanks to all that reply

I've looked on amazon for a book or 2. Would one of these be a good start?

[http://www.amazon.com/Creative-Workshop-Challenges-Sharpen-Design/dp/1600617972/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1342558997&sr=8-1&keywords=graphic+design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1600617972)

[http://www.amazon.com/Layout-Workbook-Real-World-Building-Graphic/dp/1592533523/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1342558997&sr=8-4&keywords=graphic+design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592533523)

Comment: I've looked on amazon for a book or 2. Any suggestions from this list?

Comment: Welcome to GD.  I closed this as a dupe of the general resource question for beginning designers.  While the other question originally asked about websites and you are asking about games, the core principles are the same.  If you have a more specific design problem while creating the graphics for your game, please feel free to ask again.

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of good free learning resources out there... google is your friend...

Here is just two links:

[Basic Design Principles](http://www.swinburne.edu.au/design/tutorials/design/design/)

[Principles of Design](https://www.math.duke.edu//education/ccp/resources/write/design/graphicindex.html)

BTW, it's great to see fellow devs interested in graphic design...