# Learning how to design a webpage from code, with examples in CSS3, Python, etc

Tags: website-design, css, resource-recommendations, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tips and sources for beginning designers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-sources-for-beginning-designers)

I am now completing my first website written in Python. I started learning front-end development languages such as JavaScript and CSS.

I also want to do learn how to execute the whole design layout by myself. I have very little experience in graphical design. I have made some designs 5 years ago.

Here's an example of my [first one](http://kantaki.deviantart.com/#/d13dzvj):

[image: Design example]

Where can I find resources for learning web design?

Comment: People are still using Python?

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: PHP, Ruby, Even ASP or .NET. All way more versatile and portable than Python anymore.

Comment: You obviously don't know python.

Comment: You mean like how Python cares about white space the want BASIC did? I just mean Perl or anything is more portable than Python is.

Comment: Portable? ASP and .NET (Did you mean ASP.NET?) require Windows for a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For learning purposes [Good-Tutorials -> Web-layouts](http://www.good-tutorials.com/tutorials/photoshop/web-layouts)

For inspiration: [makebetterwebsites](http://makebetterwebsites.com/)

For theoretical stuff: [web-design-theory](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/sessions/web-design-theory/)

Answer (score 1):

The best Web-Designing Resource and Learning Site - [Web Design Tuts](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com)