# Looking for an Introductory Books

Tags: reference-request

-I'm looking for an introductory books in "**Graphic Designing**" for beginners, Please help!

- A little note to Admins: If the post violates your rules... Kindly, Edit it to be in keeping with the rules... Instead of, Putting it [on Hold]... BTW, I don't mind.

Comment: Some of the information isn't directly related to your question but there is a lot of good information in this thread - [Tips and resources for beginning designers](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-resources-for-beginning-designers)

Comment: Hi KM. Unless you have something more specific that hasn't already been answered I believe the question I marked this a dupe of has what you're seeking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The Non-Designer's Design and Type Books* by Robin Williams.

If you read only one design book in your life, make it this one.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful answer, MR. Scribblemacher!

Comment: I'm closing this as a dupe. You might want to re-post your answer on that question.

Comment: Hey, I write a note to you admin... Read it & open my post.