# Where do I get started practicing (or what should I mainly work on) for graphic design in college?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I recently started college and I'm started my digital studio 101 class next semester. I always draw and fairly decent but I have no experience with the Adobe applications, I need help knowing where can I start so I wont be so new to the programs when my class start. I have the Adobe applications downloaded but every time I try to use or try to learn I have no idea where to even start.

Comment: dear god, I try and stay positive, but sometimes.

Comment: Is the class *not* supposed to teach you???

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the first design classes I took started teaching the very basics first, like how to use the programs. It's like that so anyone can start learning design without needing prior experience.

But that doesn't have to stop you from learning beforehand if you want to. I would check out this question: [Tips and resources for beginning designers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-resources-for-beginning-designers)

Answer (score 0):

> every time I try to use or try to learn I have no idea where to even start.

The problem is not where to start... it is where are you going.

If you define a goal the starting point is easy, the spot where you are right now.

Let's assume you want to make some digital manipulation, probably take someone's portrait and change the background. So the first step is to have a portrait, and have a background.

Then the middle steps are just steps, how to cut the portrait, how to paste it, how to merge it, how to integrate it.

Do not expect too much from yourself. That will be an obstacle.

If you want to produce a masterpiece... you will not get there. Instead be happy to actually make a bad composition. Then learn the errors and make a better one next time.

That is only for a specific case, but this applies to any program and everything else in life for that matter.

---

P.S. You live in the era of the information, more specific, you live in the era of youtube tutorials. Stop asking questions and go and do something! :o)

Don't watch tutorials all day. Look for ONE, and do it, not step by step, but understanding the steps you are making.

**Do one step, undo it and do it again, undo it and do it again.**

Answer (score 0):

If you can draw, then you have already got quite far. Software is much easier to force to serve what they can offer than a pen or a brush. The most difficult thing is to invent what to draw. If that also is no problem, then no problem at all - except getting started.

Get Microsoft Paint or some other as elementary and limited program. It's a part of Windows. Draw with it until you see its limitations and unflexibility. Photoshop has got 100 or 500 more functions to deliver what MS Paint doesn't.

The world of vector graphics (Illustrator) can seem confusing. Consider it as a way to make exact and repeatable shapes without a must to draw them like you must do with pencil. Of course Illustrator has also a freehand drawing tool, but generally you define what Illustrator should draw.

Start to work through Illustrator elementary tutorials in parallel with Photoshop after you have met the limits of MS Paint.

Comment: Vector graphics is easier iff you start with that and then move to pixel graphics. Its easier to go from a deeper understanding to more flexibility but the other way is much much more painful