# Beginning Design Classes/Info Advice

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am a complete novice to graphic design, but I want to create an image like this:

[image: map]

but using colors, text, ect. that I have picked myself. My problem is I don't even know enough to know where to start. Are images like this created in Photoshop? I'm trying to get enough info to Google more info and to know which classes at my community college I should start with since there are many.

Comment: Typically, you would not *create* such a map but simply download it from somewhere. Which format to use depends mainly on the software that you intend to use it with.

Comment: Possibly Helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-resources-for-beginning-designers

Answer (score 2):

Broad question, I can only offer a broad answer.

This type of image can be created using any graphic software including Paint, Photoshop and Gimp. Although for stuff like shapes and solid colors you're better off using Illustrator or Inkscape.

One important thing you need to learn is the distinction between vector and raster (bitmap) images. What's better for the image in your example (if you're not asking specifically about creating maps) is to use vector software like Inkscape or Illustrator. From there you can export it to whatever format you need

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into classes on Illustrator.