# Are there any textbooks/works on Graphic Design that are objectively seen as the best?

Tags: resource-recommendations, book

I'm looking to read a textbook or a work about graphic design or typography that is considered to be essential or the best for its field, and in particular, I would like one that is somewhat old and has stood the test of time.  It could be either technicalities of design or philosophy of design or something else, but it needs to teach concepts that can be applied timelessly; If the book covers the ins and outs of Adobe Photoshop or Illustrator and how to use the software, that isn't helpful to me.  I would like a book that teaches a way of thinking that can be applied no matter what the software or hardware used, as a good designer needs only their mind to produce a piece of art.

An example of what I'm looking for is a book from the field of programming: SICP. This is an ideal example as it has withstood decades of use and is still relevant today because it teaches concepts rather than the nitty-gritty details of the language used.

This is not a subjective question, I am asking for a specific type of book and not your favourite book. Any recommendations would preferably be written by a reputable graphic designer, professor, or have been used in a college course.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Graphic Design, unlike programming SICP, is inherently a *subjective* field. There is **no** "right" and "wrong" when it comes to *design*. Therefore there can be **no** "best" source for direction, aesthetics, or education.

What one designer feels is a *must* another designer may ignore completely. This can be seen in decades upon decades of work by various *notable* designers.

- If you are drawn to the Bauhaus style of design, you get a book on Bauhaus.
- If you are drawn to minimalism, you get a book on minimalism.
- If you like using grids.. you get a book on grid systems.
- If you want to focus on typography, you get a book on typography
- etc.

What you are asking for does not exist for *graphic design*. The field is itself too subjective to have a definitive be-all-end-all source. Designers spend *years* learning and honing their skills related to myriad design techniques, either through formal education or on-the-job training. That really can't be boiled down to a single text book, or even a small series of text books. You'd need at least a dozen or more.

It is **only** the **technical** implementations of design which can be black and white, right or wrong. And in that case, source material would need to be directed at the reproduction method. Print production is *vastly* different than web production, which is *vastly* different than sign production, etc.

- Related: [Tips and resources for beginning designers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-resources-for-beginning-designers)

Comment: THeres no best even in programming

Comment: But programming is definitive.. you do it right or it won't run. There's no such thing as "right" design, only "right" production set ups.

Comment: No, programming is not as definitive as you think. There is no such thing as the right code, just different choices.

Comment: I understand what you are alluding to. However, I still think there *is* a "right" when programming. There's an end goal.. a processes to perform. The code *must* perform that process or it is incorrect. Now, you may be able to get that result in a number of ways, which is more a matter of choice, but one can't decide to simply  ignore the language specifications -- design has none of those constraints. Paul Rand was a **vastly** different designer than Saul Bass or Massimo Vignelli -- they were all great, but didn't follow any common "rules". Every programmer **must** follow language rules.

Comment: Just because engineers obsess about the process and try to codify it does not mean that there isn't a terribly broad freedom in coding. Yeah the computer needs exact instructions of it does things wrong, however the programmer defines what is the goal. Even your designers must follow the rules set by their medium, its just that you have a tendency not to reflect so much on the process, and tweak it to perfection and worry more about the end result. (some more than others) Likewise, i as a programmer do not have to follow the language specs, i can do whatever i want with tools that i want.

Comment: The main difference is that coding as a profession is much more of a team sport. So the programmer is much more constrained by what is generally understood by peers than a designer. The programming language constrains me much less than the other programmers around me. Its just that wild code like this is almost unusable as a investment for the future, which is what programming is about. So while you can find wildly artistic code in something like code golf or underhanded programming contests, nobody actually wants to buy stuff like that.

Comment: So when you program without these constraints then, yeah, coding is just as free form as graphic design. Just dont expect me to change the code later. I can redo it  but dont ask me to do it faster than the initial code. But doing it fasteris after all the purpose of commercial programming so we tend not to do it except in hobby projects. People who pay for our code have vastly different proprieties.

Comment: @joojaa please don't get me wrong. I'm absolutely **not** trying to state that there's no freedom or aesthetic to writing code. There is by all means. My point is that *design* doesn't have the same limitations, that's all. Sure a bad design may fail to inform, sell, or whatever. However it's *not* quantifiable to the same degree as a string of code which just errors or fails to perform a given task.Incorrect code, however it's written will clearly work or not... incorrect design will still work, it'll simply work to a lesser degree than good design.

Comment: And it's to that end, that a single source for "what is best" is fairly impossible to nail down for design - it's **all** subjective and never absolutely quantifiable, Whereas with code only the aesthetics of *how* code is written/structured is subjective but the goal is *always* objective, and absolutely quantifiable.

Comment: What is best is impossible to pin down even for code. OP is wrong there is no single best book in progreamming either.

Comment: @joojaa I didn't mean that SICP is the absolute best, it was just an example.

Comment: @jstowell then you understand why there is no best design book.

Comment: @Scott I have to agree with joojaa, programming has no right or wrong way to do something.  There are several different ways to solve a problem, and there is no definitive right way to solve one.  Yes, you have to adhere to the syntax and grammar of a language, but the way that you use the the language is up to the programmer.  Two different people could both write different methods of solving a problem and they are both equally good.

Comment: @joojaa yes, the suggested duplicate actually solves my problem.  I guess I just didn't word my question right.

Comment: I do write PHP/ASP/MySQL as well as HTML/CSS/jQuery.. So, I'm not *completely* clueless as to programming. I may not know some of the more advanced languages, but I do understand the structure and how it is mailable in the hands of someone who understands it. I still think it is vastly different than design.

Comment: +1 to that.  Python *does* say that there is only one best "pythonic" way to solve a problem, but I don't believe in that.  I also write HTML/CSS/JS, as well as Lisp/Scheme/Racket

Comment: @Scott I know. But i do also all those pursuits and from my point of view its the same.