# Where can I learn how to lay things out beautifully?

Tags: education

As part of my job, I create learning materials, e-learning courses and PPT decks.

I'd love to learn how to lay things out beautifully, pick the right images and colours to make learning materials more engaging.

I know the basics of design principles and I've taken some lessons from Coursera, Hack Design and Lynda.com. I've been intentional about applying what I've learned and I also take time to review popular sites like Dabbble and Behance to get ideas.

But I still feel my progress is very slow. Is there a website, a course (paid or non-paid) or a bootcamp class (in Toronto) that you would recommend that I check out?

I'd really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tips and resources for beginning designers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-resources-for-beginning-designers)

Answer (score 1):

I'd start here - the University of Toronto Department of Visual Studies - Design:

> **Design**
>
> The Design course is intended to familiarize students with the basic elements of design through exposure to the three software applications most commonly used in graphic design: Adobe Creative Suite CS5 (Illustrator, Photoshop and InDesign). The four-year program covers aspects of typography, colour, page layout, logo design, binding and design history. Students are given a variety of design problems, each drawing on distinct conceptual and technical skills....
>
> ...This course is intended to introduce students to the basic elements, procedures and terminology of graphic design. Students will learn how to use the expressive qualities of words, colours and images and to combine all three in effective solutions to unique design problems. Creative experimentation is encouraged to broaden students' conception of design and its application in other design and art related disciplines...

[Link to the appropriate Uni Toronto page](https://www.utm.utoronto.ca/dvs/design)

That will, undoubtedly, help.