# Best place for looking at top quality UI designs?

Tags: website-design, interface-design, resource-recommendations, inspiration

I'm basically looking for a website where I can check out many good UI designs, so I can improve my taste.

I know there's dribbble! But designs on trifle are usually designed to look pretty on dribbble feed, and necessarilly with actual UX on mind. (Meaning they tend to be overly effective).

So I'm looking for a place with real apps designs.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Do you know there is a dedicated UX Stack Exchange: https://ux.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this Q&A](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-resources-for-beginning-designers/) also

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I'm looking for ideas I head over to [Site Inspire](https://www.siteinspire.com) which is an actual list of recent and live and mostly high-end websites, not just the random cute, mostly useless stuff you see piled up on Dribbble applied to the latest iPhone model renderings.