# What could I do to make these flyers less amateur and more professional?

Tags: interface-design, critique, design-principles

here are some flyers I've designed in the past that we've used for functions. I know they are all amateur but I would like to get better and am welcome to suggestions on what I could do better. I would really like to end up having my flyers look professional. Please, provide critique feedback for the flyer designs. I know these events are already over but I figured if I provided the work I've done in the past it would help me in the future. I put this post in a few groups because I didn't know what other group(s) to tag.

Side note: I do have other flyers created that we did not use so I figured I'd share those in a different post. This is my first post here for feedback and my 2nd post ever for this site.

The silhouette of the people pictured is purposely me blocking out the real picture of the people.
I don't know how the picture text description is going to go so I'll make a list of the most recent to the first flyer below.

The Let there be light theme was the first one of 2023. Created in Gimp.

The finger of God flyer was done in 2022. Created in Gimp.

The elevation flyer was done in 2022. I used Microsoft word to create this one because I was having a hard time with Gimp.

The red text dominion word festival was the first flyer I had ever done and it was in 2021. This was done in Microsoft Word.

[image: The RED txt dominion word festival was done in 2021 [1]][image: The let there be light flyer is one done recently in 2023]

[image: The Elevation flyer is one from 2022 lol obvi.]

[image: The purple dominion word flyer was 2022]

Comment: Possibly Helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-resources-for-beginning-designers

Comment: I think you will find that trying to squeeze less stuff in your flyers make them seem better. Also you should probably opt to use inkscape, illustrator, affinity designer or if you must use office use powerpoint for your design, though i dont recommend that. Also use a font pairing of somekind.

Comment: @joojaa Thank you!! One thing I guess I forgot to mention is I am told to have certain criteria so I am told what information has to be on the flyer regardless of if i think its too much. That is definitely one thing I forgot to mention. So everything on there is what they want on the flyer. I too feel some of it is too much to put on there or sometimes I will make a few things smaller to have it be less but then they will want it bigger so I make it bigger. I agree on less stuff but like I stated some of the stuff I'm required to put in.

Comment: Its your job to make sure you have useful data. If you cant fit something then you need to communicate that it does not fit. Ultimately your the proxy for the user, if something is really important to the client but not the user you need to communicate that. Designs become bad if you let your clients dictate what to do. See for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zx084IJnKkI

Comment: @joojaa. That makes sense and I've expressed before that it looks to busy and its more this is what they want. I wish i could upload pics to show you examples of what I have been given of the style they want to be replicated. I could private message you examples if that is alright.

Comment: @joojaa I have included examples in the post now of what I was given that they prefer design-wise, so no need to private message you regarding that.

Comment: Really, the examples they gave you are miles away, much better than any of your attempts. When a client shows examples, they probably take those as a reference. READ: THEY PROBABLY LIKE THE EXAMPLES :)))

Comment: @Lucian yes, I get that they like the examples but trying to mirror that knowing you are miles away, and also trying to not make it all too cluttered is a learning process.
The examples they gave, am I incorrect in seeing them and thinking its too much all at once? Not knocking it but maybe along w/me having no skill its a mix of opposite design styles/aesthetics (more modern vs old school).

Comment: @Lucian, how you put it miles away. Yes, when I first got the examples, aside from what I thought mentioned above I was like um these are professionals, don't expect professional level from me LOL so I just did what I could. I am grateful for the opportunity but know I have a lot of growing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the best design you have is honestly "Elevation 2022". Why?

You have only 3 things on your flyer. The things users need. What, when, where that's it. If you were to remove all graphic elements from the flyer, using good indentation on the table, and avoiding your borders, you'd be golden. Then you would have 2 levels of hierarchy so you can easily include the picture too.

Now adding the image of the persons is a bit problematic in your flyers, it seems to me that this part is being elevated as the most important. Only you can say if it is though.

Now typographically the "Finger of god" is the best. Try redoing that, also by aligning the list of dates properly, try moving the persons to the left and get rid of the small text like "Theme:"

But really use a margin

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. The pic is not the most important part but that was my concern as designing it too is that I feel at some points it indirectly takes away from the event theme itself which is the whole goal is the theme/event. So I try to make it smaller and put it to the side so it doesn't stand out as much but its still there. Some stuff required (like at times Theme) is what is wanted. I do appreciate the information you gave me it helps me know what is good and what to stay away from on each. What do you mean by use a margin? Like white space?

Answer (score 2):

These are really bad designs in my humble opinion. Terribly bad, no offence :) There's so much to fix, it is like everything needs to be fixed.

In your particular case honestly I suggest getting some ready made flyer templates and punch in your pictures and text. There are many flyer templates around for 5$ a piece, in every possible style, they are made for people who lack the skills or the time to create custom work, and you don't have to think about the design.

You can also hire people online for another 10$ they will take a flyer template and drop in your content, so you don't have to even touch the actual software.

Not sure this is the answer you needed, but it looks like the quicker fix here.

Comment: I appreciate your honesty, I agree they are bad. One thing I forgot to mention is that of the content that is needed on the flyer, I have to have specific content/wording on there so if they want certain text added, I have to put it there. I try less stuff and I can't really do that when Im being informed we want xyz on this flyer & then if they say add a picture or make the text bigger or smaller then im doing the best I can w/what the client wants. ill look at your suggestions, didnt know they even made ready-made flyer templates. Hopefully the templates will help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take text from the flyer down and figure out what you want to say.
2. Check spelling and correct all typos.
3. Find one thing that you want to highlight
4. Put everything together without any text effects or backgrounds.

Comment: Thank you. To the 1st point, what they want to say is the theme on all flyers &/or title. 2 things they want highlighted: festival (dominion word) &/or theme. Elevation wasn't a themed festival just the 'series' they were doing at that time. 

How do I highlight the 1 thing that you mention in point 3, when they want the theme & festival made known? 

Is putting it together w/out any text or background supposed to help focus?
so you can see, okay it's these things I want to highlight & made known, let's see how I can best do that by adding color or effects.